# how ctrl.$setViewValue(undefined); , ctrl.$render(); and scope.$digest(); working in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I want to empty and reset the value of an input tag from a listener.

```
.on('click', function(e) {
    if(elem.hasClass('v')) {
        elem.removeClass('v').val(undefined);
        ctrl.$setViewValue(undefined); //how to in angular2?
        ctrl.$render(); //how to in angular2?
        scope.$digest(); //how to in angular2?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to reference the control associated with the input. Then you can call the `updateValue` method on this control.

Here is a sample:

```
this.formCtrl = formBuilder.group({
  someInput: [ '', ... ]
});

this.formCtrl.controls.someInput.updateValue('');
```

Here is the way to link the controls with the form input:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="formCtrl">
  <input [ngFormControl]="formCtrl.controls.someInput"/>
</form>
```

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/